# regular expression for date, time and phone not matching

Tags: python, regex

```
29/11/16, 12:22 AM - ‪+91 99102 28632‬
```

I want to write a regular expression to match this pattern. I wrote something like this -

```
\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2},\s\d?\d:\d{2}\s(AM|PM)\s\-\s\+91\s\d{5}\s\d{5}
```

But it's not matching with the pattern. I'm using Python's inbuilt Re module to compile the pattern and the finditer method to find the matches and create an interator. But, actually, there are no matches found with this.

When I used sublime text to test my regex, I noticed that it worked till

`\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2},\s\d?\d:\d{2}\s(AM|PM)\s\-\s`

But as soon as I added `\+` it stopped recognizing the regex. Any solutions?

Comment: Your **input** is the problem, not the regex. Take a look with `print(repr(inputvalue))`, you'll get `'29/11/16, 12:22 AM - \u202a+91 99102 28632\u202c'`. Those are direction markers.

Comment: Hint: `'29/11/16, 12:22 AM - ‪+91 99102 28632'.replace('\u202a',  '')`

Answer (score 0):

There's a hidden left-to-right embedding character right after space after the "-" in your string. With that removed, your regex works fine:

```
In [ ]: import re
   ...: string = "29/11/16, 12:22 AM - ‪+91 99102 28632‬"
   ...: pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2},\s\d?\d:\d{2}\s(AM|PM)\s\-\s\+91\s\d{5}\s\d{5}")
   ...: re.findall(pattern, string)
Out[ ]: []

In [ ]: string = string.replace("\u202a", "")
   ...: re.findall(pattern, string)
Out[ ]: ['AM']
```